# _swift and __C errors with react native ios build

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

this is the first time for me building an IOS app.
I am getting these errors on xcode:

I have already added a File.swift including `import Foundation`

```
Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for (extension in Foundation):__C.NSOperationQueue.SchedulerTimeType
Undefined symbol: (extension in Foundation):__C.NSOperationQueue.SchedulerTimeType.init(Foundation.Date) -> (extension in Foundation):__C.NSOperationQueue.SchedulerTimeType
Undefined symbol: protocol conformance descriptor for __C.NSOperationQueue : Combine.Scheduler in Foundation
Undefined symbol: (extension in Foundation):__C.NSScanner.scanUpToString(Swift.String) -> Swift.String?
Undefined symbol: _swift_getFunctionReplacement
Undefined symbol: _swift_getOpaqueTypeConformance
Undefined symbol: _swift_getOrigOfReplaceable
```

My Podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'nabilah' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )


  target 'nabilahTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

Am I missing something ?